# Propriedade SelectionBrush somente a borda e sem preenchimento

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

É possível fazer a propriedade `SelectionBrush` igual como a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porque ela agora está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue código:

```
<TextBox SelectionBrush="Red" FontSize="12pt"/>
```

Quero ela somente a borda e sem preenchimento igual na primeira imagem, tem como fazer isso em WPF ?

Comment: Talvez desenhando um `Rectangle` e depois pintar a borda? E mesmo assim acho que seria bastante _tricky_!

Comment: @JoãoMartins não sei, será que vai ficar legal ?

Comment: Bonito poderia ficar, mas será bastante difícil fazer isso, mais por causa da posição do texto que pode variar.

Comment: @JoãoMartins você tem um exemplo  do código ? Pra mim ter uma noção.

Comment: O controlo tem de ser obrigatoriamente uma `TextBox`?

Comment: @JoãoMartins não.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81224/discussion-between-joao-martins-and-matheus-miranda).

Answer (score -1):

Você pode definir as propriedades da borda no próprio textbox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TbTeste" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Red"/>
```

Comment: Onde você definiu esse código ?

Comment: Não funciona com `textbox`

Comment: Alterei o exemplo colega, veja se agora te atende

Comment: Não é para pintar a borda do `TextBox`e sim pintar `SelectionBrush`.